# Jquery infinite content scroller

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for a solution, to have slider which slide images.
I found Owl carousel 2 and this don't fit my needs, as this plugin cannot do continous scroll, like for example:

http://logicbox.net/jquery/simplyscroll/horizontal.html

This plugin above fit my needs, but i realised, that this plugin can't work with images set to 100% of viewport.
So what i want to archive, is to have images scroller all the time, but i want to have images set to 100% of page. Can anybody advice?

Comment: The one you linked to says *"It was originally created in 2008 and web technology and processing speeds have increased to the point where this scrolling technique is no longer necessary."* - So maybe there is a simple CSS way to solve this. Have you tried building something yourself? Or looking for a more recent example than this one which is 8 years old?

Comment: If you are going to build something and you have questions, please be clear on the requirements. SimplyScroll, for instance, also has touch support which you may not even need.

Comment: Maybe a good starting point: [nfinite All-CSS Scrolling Slideshow - from CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/infinite-all-css-scrolling-slideshow/) Also nearly 5 years old, but still looks promising.